# urlencode only the directory and file names of a URL

Tags: php, urlencode

I need to URL encode just the directory path and file name of a URL using PHP.

So I want to encode something like `http://example.com/file name` and have it result in `http://example.com/file%20name`.

Of course, if I do `urlencode('http://example.com/file name');` then I end up with `http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffile+name`.

The obvious (to me, anyway) solution is to use `parse_url()` to split the URL into scheme, host, etc. and then just `urlencode()` the parts that need it like the path.  Then, I would reassemble the URL using `http_build_url()`.

Is there a more elegant solution than that?  Or is that basically the way to go?

Comment: That seems like the most robust solution to me.

Comment: Per documentation: urlencode is for the query part of a URL. rawurlencode for the path, but make sure to exclude slashes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

@deceze definitely got me going down the right path, so go upvote his answer.  But here is exactly what worked:

```
    $encoded_url = preg_replace_callback('#://([^/]+)/([^?]+)#', function ($match) {
                return '://' . $match[1] . '/' . join('/', array_map('rawurlencode', explode('/', $match[2])));
            }, $unencoded_url);
```

There are a few things to note:

- http_build_url requires a PECL install so if you are distributing your code to others (as I am in this case) you might want to avoid it and stick with reg exp parsing like I did here (stealing heavily from @deceze's answer--again, go upvote that thing).
- `urlencode()` is not the way to go!  You need `rawurlencode()` for the path so that spaces get encoded as `%20` and not `+`.  Encoding spaces as `+` is fine for query strings, but not so hot for paths.
- This won't work for URLs that need a username/password encoded.  For my use case, I don't think I care about those, so I'm not worried.  But if your use case is different in that regard, you'll need to take care of that.

Comment: Right, I forgot to piece the complete URL back together again. I guess one could change the regex to do non-capturing look-behinds so it only extracts and modifies the path. +1 anyway. :)

Answer (score 18):

As you say, something along these lines should do it:

```
$parts = parse_url($url);
if (!empty($parts['path'])) {
    $parts['path'] = join('/', array_map('rawurlencode', explode('/', $parts['path'])));
}
$url = http_build_url($parts);
```

Or possibly:

```
$url = preg_replace_callback('#https?://.+/([^?]+)#', function ($match) {
           return join('/', array_map('rawurlencode', explode('/', $match[1])));
       }, $url);
```

(Regex not fully tested though)

Comment: +1 for realizing that the slashes in the path will mess everything up if they are not given special handling like you did.

Comment: Nice.  The regexp does need some tweaking, but it set me down the right path.

Answer (score 1):

```
function encode_uri($url){
    $exp = "{[^0-9a-z_.!~*'();,/?:@&=+$#%\[\]-]}i";
    return preg_replace_callback($exp, function($m){
        return sprintf('%%%02X',ord($m[0]));
    }, $url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler:

```
$encoded = implode("/", array_map("rawurlencode", explode("/", $path)));
```

Comment: please explain your answer as it is an old question it is recommended you tell us how your answer is different than others already provided. Thank you.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It will encode the colon that follows the scheme. Given the input `http://example.com/file name`, it produces `http%3A//example.com/file%20name`. The correct result is `http://example.com/file%20name`.

Comment: This works just fine if you are working with a path, as indicated by the `$path` variable in the sample code.

Answer (score -1):

I think this function ok:

```
function newUrlEncode ($url) {
    return str_replace(array('%3A', '%2F'), '/', urlencode($url));
}
```

Comment: This works for the example in the question, but it is not robust. For example, it returns the wrong result if a port is specified in the URL.