# CURL did not returns any thing if the URL contains Special charters

Tags: php, curl

I want to get details from a url using CURL its works fine for normal character URL. But one of amy URL includes special character like  '**ó**'.

My URL sample is as follows:

```
http://www.abc.com/aóvek-xyz-pqr/1/8/
```

My php code is :

```
 $ch = curl_init($my_url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
 $content = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Use urlencode for $my_url.

Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329718/utf-8-url-get-with-curl

Comment: That url doesn't exist , can you provide a working url as such ? So we can test it out ?

Comment: @ПавелИванов I also tried urlencode it did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following (taken from [urlencode only the directory and file names of a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973790/urlencode-only-the-directory-and-file-names-of-a-url)):

```
$encoded_url = preg_replace_callback('#://([^/]+)/([^?]+)#', function ($match) {
                return '://' . $match[1] . '/' . join('/', array_map('rawurlencode', explode('/', $match[2])));
            }, $my_url);

$ch = curl_init($encoded_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

URL's in http can only be constructed with a specific set of characters. For every other you need to percent encode them.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

In PHP you can use urlencode

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Your code should look like this

```
 $ch = curl_init(urlencode($my_url));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
 $content = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function get_web_page( $url )
    {               
            $options = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true, 
            CURLOPT_HEADER          => false,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true, 
        );

        $ch      = curl_init( $url );
        curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
        $content = curl_exec( $ch );
        curl_close( $ch );

        return $content;
}

echo get_web_page("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ó");
```